# send current location on iPhone GPS at specific time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

So I would like to obtain my current GPS location and send it at a specific time in a day to a web service. How can I do this? Is there a way to automatically turn on the current location GPS service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run your application in background to receive location change notifications. In that case, your application will keep getting notifications **on location changes**.

By **"on location changes"**, I mean you can't check the location in a regular schedule. For example, if the phone does not move at all, say for 7 days, your application will not have a chance to send out its location as there is no way (yet) to let your application run in background at fixed time.

Comment: on location changes does what I need.. but then how do I turn on the GPS so that I can get my current location?

also where is this location change notifications? I tried searching the documentations, but can't seem to find it

Comment: Read `iOS Application Programming Guide` by Apple, Chapter 4 `Executing Code in the Background`.

Comment: so the closest is only by location changes.. I can't set it to trigger based on a certain time period?

Comment: To my best knowledge, you can't **guarantee** that your application will do a certain task at a scheduled time.